# What keyboard layout has @ on Ctrl+Alt+2?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

My girlfriend is looking for the keyboard layout that she always has used, where she says that to do the @ sign, its Ctrl+Alt+2.

So what keyboard configuration has that shortcut for the @ sign? We cant see to find it.

Comment: Sounds like it might be a Dvorak layout ...

Comment: I think AltGr + 2 or Ctrl + Alt + 2 is used for @ on most nordic/european keyboards

Comment: Windows10 is the os.

Comment: What language/country was your girlfriend operating in at the time in question? Did she use some common Keyboard layout there or was it special for the area?

Comment: Please tell us she did not create a password with an unknown keyboard layout which you now have to find...

Comment: Who knows what OS, language settings, keyboard they were using at the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AltGr + 2 normally produces **@** on most international keyboards and they also [use Ctrl + Alt as AltGr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AltGr_key#Control_+_Alt_as_a_substitute) in Windows. 
Setting keyboard layout to US-International should work.